# rviz run saved messages

Tags: rviz, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm running a program that sends visualization messages, like the ones in the [basic shape tutorial.](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes)
While running the program I saved the messages with  rostopic echo /visualization_marker > myfile.txt.
I'm looking for a way to display thoose messages in rviz, is there such a way?
I tried rostopic pub /visualization_marker visualization_msgs::MarkerArray  -f myfile.txt, but i get ERROR: invalid topic type: visualization_msgs::MarkerArray. While rviz displays this is the topic type.

Kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222083/rviz-run-saved-messages/) by [Kenavera](https://answers.ros.org/users/25226/kenavera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2015-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got it working with

> rostopic pub /visualization_marker
> visualization_msgs/Marker -f
> myfile.YAML

.

---

Originally posted by [Kenavera](https://answers.ros.org/users/25226/kenavera/) with karma: 56 on 2015-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1